# Using free inside the destructor of an object freed with delete

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, free

I have an object that I'm freeing with delete, and it has a `char*` that's being freed with free in its destructor. The reason I'm using free is because I used strdup and `malloc` in creating the `char` pointers. The reason I'm using `malloc` is because I used strdup to begin with in most code paths. Would this scenario cause memory corruption?

Comment: I think that there is a misunderstanding here, your object only holds a pointer to `another` memory zone where the chars are actually stored. Therefore you are not freeing memory contained by the object, so everything is fine.

Comment: I wouldn't think there should be a problem but did you face any issues while doing this? Curious.

Comment: You should mention how you allocated/initialized your object that contains the pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if you match calls properly i.e. `free()` for memory allocated with `malloc()` and `delete` for memory allocated with `new`, it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is correct. A class that has been `new`ed should be deallocated with `delete`, but if it owns memory that was allocated with `malloc` (either directly or indirectly) then it should deallocate that memory with `free`.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is correct. You use free() to release memory allocated with malloc() (or strdup()) and this is exactly what to do.

The requirement is that you release memory with a primitive matching the one used to allocate that memory. And this requirement is met in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. I was passing my object as a copy through a method, and it kept the `char*` across; when the function exited, that temporary object got deleted, freeing the `char*`. Now I need the `char*` after the method exited, but that's gone now. Two `*`'s and minus one fixed it.